# CSV iteration in Ruby, and grouping by column value to get last line of each group

Tags: ruby, loops, csv

I have a csv of transaction data, with columns like:

```
ID,Name,Transaction Value,Running Total,  
5,mike,5,5,  
5,mike,2,7,  
20,bob,1,1,  
20,bob,15,16,  
1,jane,4,4,  
etc...
```

I need to loop through every line and do something with the transaction value, and do something different when I get to the last line of each ID.

I currently do something like this:

```
total = ""
id = ""
idHold = ""
totalHold = ""

CSV.foreach(csvFile) do |row|
    
    totalHold = total
    idHold = id

    id = row[0]
    value = row[2]
    total = row[3]

    if id != idHold
       # do stuff with the totalHold here
    end
end
```

But this has a problem - it skips the last line. Also, something about it doesn't feel right. I feel like there should be a better way of detecting the last line of an 'ID'.

Is there a way of grouping the id's and then detecting the last item in the id group?

note: all id's are grouped together in the csv

Comment: Look at [Array#group_by](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first construct a CSV file.

```
str =<<~END
ID,Name,Transaction Value,Running Total  
5,mike,5,5  
5,mike,2,7  
20,bob,1,1  
20,bob,15,16  
1,jane,4,4
END
```

```
CSVFile = 't.csv'
File.write(CSVFile, str)
  #=> 107
```

I will first create a method that takes two arguments: an instance of [CSV::row](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html) and a boolean to indicate whether the CSV row is the last of the group (`true` if it is).

```
def process_row(row, is_last)
  puts "Do something with row #{row}"
  puts "last row: #{is_last}"
end
```

This method would of course be modified to perform whatever operations need be performed for each row.

Below are three ways to process the file. All three use the method [CSV::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) to read the file line-by-line. This method is called with two arguments, the file name and an *options hash* `{ header: true, converters: :numeric }` that indicates that the first line of the file is a header row and that strings representing numbers are to be converted to the appropriate numeric object. Here values for `"ID"`, `"Transaction Value"` and `"Running Total"` will be converted to integers.

Though it is not mentioned in the doc, when `foreach` is called without a block it returns an enumerator (in the same way that [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) does).

We of course need:

```
require 'csv'
```

**Chain `foreach` to [Enumerable#chunk](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk)**

I have chosen to use `chunk`, as opposed to [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), because the lines of the file are already grouped by `ID`.

```
CSV.foreach(CSVFile, headers:true, converters: :numeric).
    chunk { |row| row['ID'] }.
    each do |_,(*arr, last_row)|
      arr.each { |row| process_row(row, false) }
      process_row(last_row, true)
    end
```

displays

```
Do something with row 5,mike,5,5  
last row: false
Do something with row 5,mike,2,7  
last row: true
Do something with row 20,bob,1,1  
last row: false
Do something with row 20,bob,15,16  
last row: true
Do something with row 1,jane,4,4
last row: true
```

Note that

```
enum = CSV.foreach(CSVFile, headers:true, converters: :numeric).
           chunk { |row| row['ID'] }.
           each
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00007ffd1a831070>:each>
```

Each element generated by this enumerator is passed to the block and the block variables are assigned values by a process called [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition):

```
_,(*arr,last_row) = enum.next
 #=> [5, [#<CSV::Row "ID":5 "Name":"mike" "Transaction Value":5 "Running Total  ":5>,
 #        #<CSV::Row "ID":5 "Name":"mike" "Transaction Value":2 "Running Total  ":7>]]
```

resulting in the following:

```
_ #=> 5
arr
  #=> [#<CSV::Row "ID":5 "Name":"mike" "Transaction Value":5 "Running Total  ":5>] 
last_row
  #=> #<CSV::Row "ID":5 "Name":"mike" "Transaction Value":2 "Running Total  ":7>
```

See [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).

I have followed the convention of using an underscore for block variables that are used in the block calculation (to alert readers of your code). Note that an underscore is a valid block variable.<sup>1</sup>

**Use [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) in place of `chunk`**

```
CSV.foreach(CSVFile, headers:true, converters: :numeric).
    slice_when { |row1,row2| row1['ID'] != row2['ID'] }.
    each do |*arr, last_row|
      arr.each { |row| process_row(row, false) }
      process_row(last_row, true)
    end
```

This displays the same information that is produced when `chunk` is used.

**Use [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) to step through the enumerator `CSV.foreach(CSVFile, headers:true)`**

```
enum = CSV.foreach(CSVFile, headers:true, converters: :numeric)
row = nil
loop do
  row = enum.next
  next_row = enum.peek 
  process_row(row, row['ID'] != next_row['ID'])
end
process_row(row, true)
```

This displays the same information that is produced when `chunk` is used. See [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#peek](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek).

After `enum.next` returns the last `CSV::Row` object `enum.peek` will generate a `StopIteration` exception. As explained in its doc, `loop` handles that exception by breaking out of the loop. `row` must be initialized to an arbitrary value before entering the loop so that `row` is visible after the loop terminates. At that time `row` will contain the `CSV::Row` object for the last line of the file.

<sup>1 IRB uses the underscore for its own purposes, resulting in the block variable `_` being assigned an erroneous value when the code above is run.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. ruby has got your back.

```rb
grouped = CSV.table('./test.csv').group_by { |r| r[:id] }

# Then process the rows of each group individually:
grouped.map { |id, rows|
  puts [id, rows.length ]
}
```

Tip: You can access each row as a hash by using `CSV.table`

```rb
CSV.table('./test.csv').first[:name]
=> "mike"
```